# Can you open a VS2012 Project without the solution projects opening

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2012 solution with numerous projects in it.

Is it possible to open one of the projects without the entire solution opening?  When I try and open one of the csproj files, the entire solution projects load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The best option would be to create a new solution, and add the specific project you want to it. This will give the project a solution of it's own.

Comment: Yep.  That's what I just did.  Works for me.